# Is it somehow possibe to link a mathematical axis unit expression from a list or dataframe onto an ggplot axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, automation, expression, axis-labels

I wonder if it's possible to craft a semi-automatic parsing of 'complicated' mathematical expressions into the axis of ggplot by maintaining some sort of lookup table?

So, for example, for data-mining, I regularly have to produce hundreds of scatterplots, which I want to discuss with colleagues. To do so, I want correct axis-legends, of course - this is rather cumbersome.
Here a simple example of what would like to read out from a database into the labs() by using a formula: `expression(paste(delta^{18},"O (\u2030)")`
So, what I was wondering is if there's a way to link those labs() to predefined lists or tables in a way like labs(y = list[3])? 
This works just fine for simple names like: "Dissolved oxygen saturation / %", but when trying the same for the above, it generates:

```
paste(delta^{
    18
}, "O (‰)")
```

(including the breaks - which is obviously not what I want)

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could tinker with the `math_format()` function from the scales package a bit to take in pre-substituted expressions:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

splitiris <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# Example expressions
exprs <- list(
  substitute(10^.x),
  substitute(log[.x]~"(%)"),
  substitute(frac(.x, 2))
)

# Near-copy of scales::math_format
math_format2 <- function(expr = subsitute(10^.x), format = force) {
  .x <- NULL
  subs <- function(x) {
    do.call("substitute", list(expr, list(.x = x)))
  }
  function(x) {
    x <- format(x)
    ret <- lapply(x, subs)
    ret <- as.expression(ret)
    ret[is.na(x)] <- NA
    names(ret) <- names(x)
    ret
  }
}

# Generate plots
plots <- lapply(seq_along(splitiris), function(i) {
  ggplot(splitiris[[i]], aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = math_format2(exprs[[i]]))
})

plots[[1]] + plots[[2]] + plots[[3]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hm, that's interesting, but not quite what I was looking for. 
Maybe my question was ambiguous. What I am looking for is a way to store axis titles, in a lookup table that I can refer to. For example instead of needing to write labs( x = "bquote("sepal area / "~m^3) , y = bquote(O[2]~"-production / mg "~d^{-1})), 
I'd like to use something like  labs(x = axistitles[15], y = axistitles[8])